# Adding Images to Database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm making a quiz project in android studio and I want every question to come with a specific image. The quiz is to help kids learn Spanish so if they question was how to say cat in Spanish there would be an image of a cat.

At the moment, it creates an SQL table with the options, question and answers.

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT)";
```

Setting question one for example looks like this (using an addition `q` as example):

```
   private void addQuestion() {
       Question q1 = new Question("5+2 = ?", "7", "8", "6", "5", "7");
       this.addQuestion(q1); 
   }
```

How would I add a specific image to this i.e in this case I might want to pick the image as a cat and in the next question I might want the image to be a dog

```
private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; //option d
```

I tried using this format (the same as a question) except with Image instead of String but that lead to problems.

Any advice on how I'd start this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create a folder in the External or Internal memory of the device place the photo there and save the path of that photo in your db then by using Picasso or any other image loading library you can show the photo from the external or internal directory

Answer (score 0):

Use [Andrid Assets Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to make images for diferent screen resolutions.
Add thouse images in res/drawable folder.Then make an int property named mImageId in your Question class and in SQL Table. The constructor may looks like this:

```
Question q1 = new Question("5+2 = ?", "7", "8", "6", "5", "7", R.drawable.cat);
```

I hope you will do it better than that, but anyways...

You should make an ImageView in xml UI component, in order to put the image in to it.

In the java class who you loads the Quiz question you can use:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.<your ImageView id>)
image.setImageResource(q1.getImageId());
```